# GeneralizedEigenSolver not giving eigenvectors in Eigen library

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, eigen, eigenvector

I am new to the Eigen library and trying to solve a generalized eigen value problem. As per the documentation of the GeneralizedEigenSolver template class in Eigen library [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1GeneralizedEigenSolver.html) I am able to get the eigen values but not the eigen vectors. Seems like the eigenvectors() member function is not implemented. Is there any other way I can generate the eigen vectors once I know the eigen values.I am using Eigen 3.2.4.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear to be implemented yet. At the end of the `compute` function there is:

```
 m_eigenvectorsOk = false;//computeEigenvectors;
```

indicating that they're not actually calculated. Additionally, the `eigenvectors()` function is commented out and looks like (note the TODO):

```
//template<typename MatrixType>
//typename GeneralizedEigenSolver<MatrixType>::EigenvectorsType GeneralizedEigenSolver<MatrixType>::eigenvectors() const
//{
//  eigen_assert(m_isInitialized && "EigenSolver is not initialized.");
//  eigen_assert(m_eigenvectorsOk && "The eigenvectors have not been computed together with the eigenvalues.");
//  Index n = m_eivec.cols();
//  EigenvectorsType matV(n,n);
//  // TODO
//  return matV;
//}
```

If you wanted eigenvalues from a single matrix you could use `EigenSolver` like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXf> es;
    Eigen::MatrixXf A = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(4,4);
    es.compute(A);

    std::cout << es.eigenvectors() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is a generalised Eigen value problem hence involves two matrices. So es.compute(A) wont work for me. However I am able to get the required eigen value. Is it possible to generate the corresponding eigen vector ?

Comment: @rotating_image No. The eigenvalues for the `GeneralizedEigenSolver` are computed in the `compute` function (where `m_eigenvectorsOk = false;//computeEigenvectors;`), which is called by the `GeneralizedEigenSolver(const MatrixType& A, const MatrixType& B, bool computeEigenvectors = true)` c'tor. I'll update the answer with the unimplemented Eigen code that you want.

Comment: @rotating_image Do you know how to calculate the eigenvectors from the `QZ` matrix (whatever that is)? That appears to be the code that is not yet implemented.

Comment: I confirm that this feature is still missing, and it is waiting for someone to implement it ;) This corresponds to the [dtgevc](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dtgevc.f) routine in Lapack.

Answer (score 1):

It's strange that this isn't implemented, the docs suggest that it is. It's definitely worth asking on the Eigen mailing list or filing a ticket, maybe somebody is working on this and it's in the latest repository.

I have in the past used the `GeneralizedSelfAdjointEigenSolver` and it definitely produces eigenvectors. So if you know that both your matrices are symmetric, you can use that.

If your matrices are very small, as a quick fix you could apply the standard `EigenSolver` to `M^{-1} A` since

```
A x = lambda * M x    <==>   M^{-1} A x = lambda * x,
```

but obviously this requires you to compute the inverse of your right-hand side matrix which is very expensive, so this is really a last resort.

If all else fails, you could pull in a dedicated eigensolver library, say, [FEAST](http://www.ecs.umass.edu/~polizzi/feast/index.htm), or use the LAPACK routines.

Comment: Already tried your fix but in my case M is always non invertible in my case.